# How do I remove these nodes from a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

When I run the code, it will not remove the nodes like I want it to. They stay on the list. I think that there may be issues with the .cpp and header file, but I am not sure. This is my first time messing with Linked Lists, so any help would be appreciated! Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "NumberList.cpp"

using namespace std;

int node(){
    int i,j;
    char answer;
    NumberList list; //create a new linked list

    bool MainMenu = true;

    while (MainMenu){
    cout<<"Please make a selection:\n1.Add a starting point\n2.Remove a starting point.\n3.Quit"<<endl;
    cin>>answer;

    if(answer == '1'){
        bool keepGoing = true;
        while (keepGoing){
        cout<<"Enter the row: ";
        cin>>i;
        cout<<"Enter the column: ";
        cin>>j;
        list.add(i,j);
        cout<<"You added "<<i<<"and "<<j<<endl;
        //list.add(4,5);
        //list.add(3,6);
        cout<<"Here is the list: "<<endl;
        list.displayList();
        cout<<"Would you like to add another point? y/n"<<endl;
        cin>>answer;
            if (answer == 'y')
            {
                keepGoing=true;
            }
            else if (answer == 'n')
            {
                keepGoing=false;
            }//end else
        }
    }
    else if (answer == '2'){
        int x,y;
        cout<<"Here are the points chosen: "<<endl;
        list.displayList();
        cout<<"Which point do you want to remove?\nRow: "<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        cout<<"Column: "<<endl;
        cin>>y;
        list.remove(x,y);
        cout<<"Updated list: "<<endl;
        list.displayList();
    }
    else if (answer == '3'){
        MainMenu = false;
    }//end else if
    else{
        cout<<"Unable to process"<<endl;
        }
    }//end keepGoing
}

int main()
{
    node();
}
```

NumberList.cpp:

```
#include "NumberList.h"
using namespace std;

void NumberList::add(int i, int j)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        head = new ListNode(i,j);
    else
    {
        //The node is not empty. Use nodePtr to traverse the list
        ListNode *nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr->next != NULL)
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;

        //nodePtr->next is NULL so nodePtr points to the last node.
        //Create a new node and put it after the last node
        nodePtr->next = new ListNode(i,j);
    }
}

void NumberList::displayList()
{
    ListNode *nodePtr = head; //Start at head of the list
    while(nodePtr)
    {
        //Print the value in the current node
        cout<<"("<<nodePtr->i<<","<<nodePtr->j<<")";
        //Move onto the next node
        nodePtr = nodePtr -> next;
    }
}

void NumberList::remove(int x, int y)
{
    ListNode *nodePtr, *previousNodePtr;

    //if the list is empty, do nothing;
    if (!head) {
        cout<<"The list is empty"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    //int i,j;
    int j;
    //Determine if the first node is the one to delete.
    if (head-> i&&j == x&&y)

    {
        nodePtr = head;
        head = head ->next;
        delete nodePtr;
    }
    else
    {
        //Initialize notePtr to the head of the list;
        nodePtr = head;
        //Skip the nodes whose value member is not number
        while(nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr-> i&&j != x&&y)
            {
                    previousNodePtr = nodePtr;
                    nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
            }
        //Link the previous node to the next node after
        // nodePtr, then delete nodePtr
        if (nodePtr)
        {
            previousNodePtr -> next = nodePtr->next;
            delete nodePtr;
        }
    }
}
```

NumberList.h:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class NumberList
{
    protected:
    //Declare a class for the list node.
    struct ListNode
    {
        int i,j;
        ListNode *next;
        ListNode(int i1, int j1, ListNode *next1=NULL)
        {
            i=i1;
            j=j1;
            next=next1;
        }
    };
    ListNode *head;//List head pointer
    public:
        NumberList(){head=NULL;}
        //~NumberList();
        void add(int i, int j);
        void remove(int i, int j);
        void displayList();
};
```

Comment: Have you used your debugger?

Comment: Your `node` function is supposed to return an `int`, but doesn't return anything.  Undefined behavior.

Comment: Code like `if (head-> i&&j == x&&y)` is a very unusual format and makes things difficult to read; the alternative `if (head->i && j == x && y)` looks meaningless. You don't initialise `j`, as your compiler should have warned you about.

Comment: Indeed, you seem to think `if (head-> i&&j == x&&y)` means `if (head->i == x && head->j == y)`...

Comment: @KenY-N Awesome! That solved the problem! I've never really used the and statement before this program either. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Needed to add the method call with the structure pointer operator on both sides of the and sign. Instead of:

```
if (head-> i&&j == x&&y)
```

Did this:

```
if (head-> i==x && head->j==y)
```

Comment: In the else-case of the function`remove()`, the while-loop `while(nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->i&&nodePtr->j != x&&y)` shall be replaced by `while ((nodePtr != NULL) && ((nodePtr->i != x) || (nodePtr->j != y)))`. And the local declaration of `int j;` shall be removed.